# Efficiency of LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, database, join

I've searched extensively and increased performance through my research, but I'm still not getting results as quickly as I think are possible.

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT x.`level`, count(x.`level`) AS TOTAL FROM (
SELECT a.`level` FROM `gharaffa`.`wwlassessments` a 
LEFT JOIN `gharaffa`.`users` u on u.`pupilID` = a.`pupilID` 
WHERE a.`dateAchieved` = (
SELECT MAX(a2.`dateAchieved`) 
FROM `gharaffa`.`wwlassessments` a2 
WHERE a.`pupilID`= a2.`pupilID` && a2.`id`='867' && u.form='Y02GA' && u.enrolled='1' ) 
)x 
GROUP BY x.`level`
```

It executes on my table of 50,000 rows in 1.8 seconds. 
However, the page will run this query with different parameters 60 times. 
That's taking too long.

Originally I had this part:
u.form='Y02GA' && u.enrolled='1'

outside of the join and that took 4.20 seconds.... I've more than halved the time, but I can't help thinking it's still not as efficient as it could be.

Any pointers gratefully received. 
John :-)

Comment: How about running it with different parameters once

Comment: Can you explain what is the SQL supposed to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT x.level, count(x.level) AS TOTAL
FROM (SELECT a.level
      FROM gharaffa.wwlassessments a LEFT JOIN
           gharaffa.`users` u
           on u.`pupilID` = a.`pupilID` 
           WHERE a.dateAchieved = (SELECT MAX(a2.dateAchieved) 
                                   FROM gharaffa.wwlassessments a2 
                                   WHERE a.pupilID = a2.pupilID AND
                                         a2.id = 867 AND
                                         u.form = 'Y02GA' AND
                                         u.enrolled = 1
                                  ) 
          ) x
GROUP BY x.level;
```

This query seems way overcomplicated.  Do note two smallish changes:

- Removed single quotes around the numeric constants.  Don't use single quotes for numeric values (I presume `id` is numeric).
- Changed `&&` to `AND`.  The latter is standard SQL.

Some observations:

- The innermost subquery turns the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.
- The conditions on `u` should be in the middle `WHERE`, not the innermost `WHERE`.
- The outer subquery is not needed.

So, I would write this as:

```
SELECT a.level, COUNT(*) as TOTAL
FROM gharaffa.wwlassessments a JOIN
     gharaffa.users u
     ON u.pupilID = a.pupilID 
WHERE u.form = 'Y02GA' AND
      u.enrolled = 1 AND
      a.dateAchieved = (SELECT MAX(a2.dateAchieved) 
                        FROM gharaffa.wwlassessments a2 
                        WHERE a.pupilID = a2.pupilID AND
                              a2.id = 867
                       ) 
GROUP BY a.level;
```

For this, you want indexes on `users(form, enrolled, pupilID)` and `wwlassessments(pupilId, id, level)`.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to reply with such clarity :-) I have tried the SQL above, but it just hangs and I have to restart the mySQL service! Could that be because the indexes haven't built???

Comment: taking a look at the structure, id is actually a non integer occasionally, so I popped the ' '  back around the variable and it worked... however, it's taking 4.05 seconds, where as the original version only takes 1.25... indexes still building??? Do they build quickly? What if I use other quieries on the same time that would be faster with different indexes... can you have multiple? how does it know which to use?

Comment: Wow... OK ... I looks like you've identified an area I need to learn more about... I've added the indexes and waited a while... massive speed difference.... seems very important that I learn more about this....Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0200 sec)

Comment: @Jack . . . From 1.8 seconds to 0.02 seconds.  That's 98.9% speed up.  Not bad.